# Search multiple fields of the same collection using meteor-autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am using [mizzao/meteor-autcomplete](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete) in order to return matched items from a MongoDB collection when you type a query.

I am able to successfully do this if I only search for one field, but it does not let me search multiple fields of the same collection.

I attempted to do it this way:

```
Template.foo.helpers({
    settings: function() {
            return {
                position: 'bottom',
                limit: 5,
                rules: [
                     {
                         collection: Models,
                         field: 'name',
                         matchAll: true,
                         template: Template.standardLegends,
                    },
                    {
                        collection: Models,
                        field: 'createdBy',
                        matchAll: true,
                        template: Template.standardLegendsOwner,
                    },
                ],
            };
        },
});
```

I looked through github open issues and there was one similar issue where they say to use the **selector** function in order to return multiple fields but I wasn't really able to understand what I am supposed to do.

Here is a link to that thread:
https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete/issues/13

### Any help would be appreciated.

Further Explanation

Here is an example of a dataset that is returned from my Models Collection:

```
0: 
    _id:"KwTZmBC5qBcwK7kzR"
    name:"drillCase.stl"
    units:"mm"
    createdBy:"Bob M"
    createdDate:"Tue Aug 29 2017 03:19:10 GMT-0400 (EDT)"
1:
    _id:"ljknbgwlkejb56"
    name:"cone.stl"
    units:"mm"
    createdBy:"Michael C"
    createdDate:"Tue Aug 29 2017 03:45:10 GMT-0400 (EDT)"
```

Here is the template I am currently using to display the autocomplete results:

```
<template name="standardLegendsOwner">
    <span class="fieldName" style="width: 500px">{{name}}</span>
</template>
```

So let's say I want to return all of the items that are associated with the 'createdBy' value 'Bob M'. Right now if I type Bob M, I get returned back 'drillCase.stl' instead because we are searching by the 'name' field and in the template we are return the 'name' value.

So my question is, is it possible to setup up a conditional statement inside of the template to say something like, if the field you matched was 'name' return name values, otherwise return 'createdBy' values.

The issue I get right now is, if I type in Bob M. and he is associated with more than one object, then it return first value that matches with him.

Answer (score 0):

The `selector` function basically needs to return the `query` object that is to be used by `.find()`. To look at multiple fields you will also need `$or:`

```
Template.foo.helpers({
  settings() {
    return {
      position: 'bottom',
      limit: 5,
      rules: [
        {
           collection: Models,
           field: 'name',
           matchAll: true,
           template: Template.standardLegends,    
           selector(match) {
             regex = new RegExp(match, 'i')
             return {$or: [{'name': regex}, {'createdBy': regex}]}
           },
         }
       ],
     };
   },
});
```

I read the documentation for mizzao:autocomplete a bit more and realized that it actually returns all the fields from the matching documents. This means you have a lot of flexibility in your results template. For example you can do:

```
<template name="standardLegendsOwner">
  <span class="fieldName" style="width: 500px">{{name}} - {{createdBy}}</span>
</template>
```

Since you know one of those fields will be a match. You could also write a helper that creates exactly what you want to see.

Comment: Thank you that makes more sense now. Is there anyway to show a unique template depending on which field is returned?

Currently the Template.standardLegends has a span tag that return the {{name}} field. Is there any way to specify a unique template depending on what value was matched? 

Or perhaps inside the template set up conditions showing different fields depending on what was matched?

Comment: To be more specific, If I currently search by the field 'createdBy' and select an autocomplete option, it still searched for Mongo by the 'name' field. So instead of returning all of the items in the collection containing a 'createdBy' query, it returns a 'name' item that happens to match the 'createdBy' field as well. I hope I'm explaining this properly, apologies in advance.

Comment: I think that mizzao:autocomplete only returns one field from the matching documents even though here it's searching across two fields. I could imagine it would give you results that don't match the displayed field at all if the other field matches. I'm not sure you can force it to return the value of the field it matched on.

Comment: Maybe showing some sample documents and what you expect to come back might help explain the problem.

Comment: Added some more info, hope this helps.

Comment: When I tried to use mizzao:autocomplete I eventually had to write my own autocomplete code. This turned out to be far easier than trying to make the package handle the more convoluted cases. It's pretty easy to do with a subscription that takes the search parameters.

Comment: Forget my previous comment about only one field being returned, it returns the entire document.